# How to include forked and edited repo of github in my netbeans php project?

Tags: git, netbeans, github, composer-php, netbeans-8

I have a dependency on this module

https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth

However I have to make a change to module in order for it to work
but one should never directly change a vendor module.

How can I use the forked and edited module as dependency instead of original module ?

Is it possible using composer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I have to make a change to module in order for it to work but one should never directly change a vendor module.

You can fork it to your github account and then add your local copy to your workdir.

> How can I use the forked and edited module as dependency instead of original module ?
>   Go to the github repo, click on the fork and it will copy it to your github account.

Now you can add it directly or to use submodule to do it.

Read more about submodules here:
[using submodules in git for the timid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909015/using-submodules-in-git-for-the-timid/35978586#35978586)

Comment: How to do it using composer ? I want this to be done via composer so that it will resolve all the dependencies (including forked)

Comment: Read this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer and follow teh instructions

Comment: if I have have more than 2 modules that require the same thing. Should I just put the repository url one after another?

Comment: can you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147714/use-forked-repo-on-github-via-composer-as-dependency